# Accesing Android sensors in non activity class

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a Android app that has a main activity with some textviews for displaying sensor data (reading and displaying acceleration and giro data). In the onCreate method i'm calling a normal java call called SensorModule and i give the contect as a parameter to this class.

The SensorModule class implements the SensorEventListener for listining to sensor events. The object is created in the main activity onCreate method (i have some prints and i see them in the Logcat).

But the onSensorChanged method isn't called. (when i put the SensorModule code in the main activity then it works fine).

I think that i have problem with initializing the SensorModule and it sensorEventlistener but i don't know what the problem might be. Does anyone have a idea?

Below i the initializing of the SensorModule in the onCreate method of main activity:

```
SensorM = new SensorModule(this);
```

Here is the SensorClass with the where i think something goes wrong, the print in the SensorOnChange is not printed in the LogCat:

```
 package com.example.SensorModuleClass;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.content.Context;

public class SensorModule  implements SensorEventListener {

    private boolean alphaStatic = true;

    Context AppContext;

    // Constants for the low-pass filters
    private float timeConstant = 0.18f;
    private float alpha = 0.1f;
    private float dt = 0;

    // Timestamps for the low-pass filters
    private float timestamp = System.nanoTime();
    private float timestampOld = System.nanoTime();

    private int count = 0;

    // Gravity and linear accelerations components for the
    // Wikipedia low-pass filter
    private float[] gravity = new float[]
    { 0, 0, 0 };

    private float[] linearAcceleration = new float[]
    { 0, 0, 0 };

    // Raw accelerometer data
    private float[] input = new float[]
    { 0, 0, 0 }; 


    // device sensor manager
    public static SensorManager mSensorManager;
    public static SensorEventListener mSensorListener;

    // Outputs for the acceleration and LPFs
    public float[] AccelerationData = new float[3];
    public float[] AccelerationResult = new float[3];

    public SensorModule(Context Context){

        System.out.println("####  Constructor");

        AppContext = Context;

        // initialize your android device sensor capabilities
        //mSensorManager =  (SensorManager) AppContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        SensorManager  mSensorManager =  (SensorManager) AppContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        System.out.println("#### Constructor done");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        System.out.println("=======On changed called=====");
        // Get a local copy of the sensor values
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, AccelerationData, 0, event.values.length);    

        AccelerationData[0] = AccelerationData[0] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        AccelerationData[1] = AccelerationData[1] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        AccelerationData[2] = AccelerationData[2] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

        // Get result
        AccelerationResult = GetAcceleration(AccelerationData); 
    }

    public float[] GetAcceleration(float[] AccelData){

        // Get a local copy of the sensor values
        System.arraycopy(AccelData, 0, this.input, 0, AccelData.length);

        //
        count++;

        if (count > 5)
        {
            // Update the Wikipedia filter
            // y[i] = y[i] + alpha * (x[i] - y[i])
            // Get gravity values
            gravity[0] = gravity[0] + alpha * (this.input[0] - gravity[0]);
            gravity[1] = gravity[1] + alpha * (this.input[1] - gravity[1]);
            gravity[2] = gravity[2] + alpha * (this.input[2] - gravity[2]);


            // Use gravity values to get the acceleration by  substracting the 
            // gravity from the input signel(the raw acceleration data)
            linearAcceleration[0] = input[0] - gravity[0];
            linearAcceleration[1] = input[1] - gravity[1];
            linearAcceleration[2] = input[2] - gravity[2];
        }

        // Return the acceleration values of the x, y and z axis
        return linearAcceleration;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions and feedback are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SensorM = new SensorModule(getApplicationContext);`
use like this

else try to change your code like this

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity, implements SensorEventListener {
     private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
     private final Sensor mAccelerometer;

     public SensorActivity() {
         mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
         mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
     }

     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
     }

     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
     }

     public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
     }

     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i changed the object initialization in the onCreateMethod to:    SensorM = new SensorModule(getApplicationContext());. But onSensorChanged is still not called.

Comment: Thanks ill give it a try. One question: can i then just call the constructor in the onCreate method of main activity? Like this: SensrActivity SensorAct = new SensorActivity(); ?

Comment: I think u can do it.http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html  refer this link

Comment: Hi Thanks for you comments again, get the following runetime error: System service not available to Atievieties before onCreate(). Do you know how to solve this? I call the construction of SensorActivity in the main activity oncreate function.

Comment: I have fixed the problem thank you for your help! If you want to use a other activity then your solution is great. Thanks

Comment: @Roy08  can u pls tell me where can i intialize private SensorManager sensorManager;   incase of services i want to get sensors result in background using services android